# Indian passport holder travelling to Tunisia

Tags: indian-citizens, tourist-visas, visas-on-arrival, tunisia

I wanted to inquire about the tourist visa to Tunisia. I'm an Indian citizen and Indian Passport holder living in Saudi Arabia. I wish to travel to Tunisia on vacation as a tourist with my family.

Do I need to apply for a visa or is it Visa free?

Answer (score 2):

As an Indian citizen, you can enter Tunisia without a visa. You need to bring the following documents:

- Valid passport with at least 6 months validity
- Confirmed hotel booking
- Confirmed round-trip airline ticket

Source: http://www.tunisianembassy.in/tunisia.php?id=Visa